# Conditional raggedright

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Can I make (XeLa)TeX automatically use \raggedright whenever a paragraph would otherwise produce underfull or overfull boxes? (Might be useful for marginal paragraphs.)

Comment: I would simply print all margin notes ragged. justified text in narrow columns looks aweful.

Comment: You probably will prefer \RaggedRight from the ragged2e package which limits the raggedness (and allows hyphenation) but is ragged when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably will prefer `\RaggedRight` from the `ragged2e` package which limits the raggedness (and allows hyphenation) but is ragged when needed.